# Notify of Video Call

Tags: react-native, instagram, agora.io, callkit, videochat

I am building a Video Chat application in React-Native, I have successfully implemented the Video Chat feature. Now I need a mechanisim to send notification to the user to join the Video Call.
I have read **stackoverflow** and also googled a lot, all the answers suggest to use **Callkeep**.

But **Callkeep** requires me to use **Phone call account permission** to use the module. I need the notification to be handled like in Instagram, with simple notification that User A is calling you with declined and answer button only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or a similar service to send and receive notifications for your calls. You can send the channel name as the payload to accept the notification and join the call.

Comment: I am already using FCM for sending and receiving notifications,  and  i have successfully implemented the sending and receiving part even if the app is in killed/background state, but confusing part is it only making the notification to vibrate one time not for 30-40 seconds?? how to make the notification to work as a notification like from instagram videocall

Comment: From what I understand there's either standard notification using FCM, the way they are handled with depend on your device (in your case a vibration once). If you want to do a custom notification you'll have to invoke your app on the notification, something that callkeep lets you do. Or having a background service listening for the notification that triggers an app function for ringing the phone for 30 seconds.